# access to facebook page in iframe denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, cordova

i have this html on mobile app:

```
<header class="bar-title">
        <a class="button-prev" onclick="history.back(-1)">
            BACK
        </a>
        <h1 class="title">FACEBOOK</h1>
    </header>
     <div  style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-top: 42px;" >
            <iframe style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="https://www.facebook.com/pages/SOMEPAGE" ></iframe>
    </div>
```

but i get error: 
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/SOMEPAGE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

little comment: i dont have access to facebook page options

Answer (score 1):

`X-Frame-Options` is an response header.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>    or . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks,
>   by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

It means facebook blocks this kind of behaviour